# Resize Widgets with PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm a beginner of Python and PyQT. I'm trying to use QGridLayout to make the GUI, however I've got some problems when I place an image. This is how it looks without the image:

pic without image

[image]

Pretty good for me. However, when I try to add an image in the upper-right corner I get:

pic with image

[image]

Clearly isn't what I want (I'd like that part of the widget the same size as the first image i.e approximately  the size of the original title). The code is a bit long so I post just the part of the grid:

```
    wid = QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(wid)
    grid = QGridLayout()
    title = QLabel(self)
    newfont = QFont("Times", 20, QFont.Bold)
    title.setText('Interfaz Gráfica PIC18F4550')
    title.setFont(newfont)
    title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    pic = QLabel(self)
    pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('escudo.gif'))

    m = PlotCanvas(self, width=5, height=4)
    connect_btn = QPushButton('Conectar', self)
    connect_btn.setIcon(QIcon('lautaro.jpeg'))
    connect_btn.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    exit_btn = QPushButton('Salir', self)
    exit_btn.setIcon(QIcon('lautaro.jpeg'))
    exit_btn.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    disconnect_btn = QPushButton('Desconectar', self)
    disconnect_btn.setIcon(QIcon('lautaro.jpeg'))
    disconnect_btn.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    frequency_btn = QPushButton('Frecuencia', self)
    frequency_btn.setIcon(QIcon('lautaro.jpeg'))
    frequency_btn.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    duty_cycle_btn = QPushButton('Duty Cycle', self)
    duty_cycle_btn.setIcon(QIcon('lautaro.jpeg'))
    duty_cycle_btn.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred, QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    grid.addWidget(connect_btn, 1, 0, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(disconnect_btn, 3, 0, 2 ,1)
    grid.addWidget(exit_btn, 5, 0, 2, 1)
    grid.addWidget(m, 1, 1, 6, 1)
    grid.addWidget(frequency_btn, 1, 2, 3, 1)
    grid.addWidget(duty_cycle_btn, 4, 2, 3, 1)
    grid.addWidget(title, 0, 1)
    grid.addWidget(pic, 0, 2)
    wid.setLayout(grid)
```

So, the question: how can I set the widget size? Clearly in this case the widgets related to title and the label are way larger than the buttons and the graph.

Comment: son, here is a little advice, if you haven't gone too far, use QTQuick and qml instead of QtWidgets. Widgets in itself is ... son. The performace is just too much, imagine Microsoft's Fluent Design capabilities.

Comment: Is QtQuick well supported in Python? Last time I check a few months ago it wasn't the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the image to always have the same size you can set a fixed width and height as follows:

```
pic = QLabel(self)
pic.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('escudo.gif'))
pic.setFixedWidth(250)
pic.setFixedHeight(250)
```

If you want the image to have a maximum size but it should resize and get smaller if the window gets smaller you can use the following:

```
pic.setMaximumWidth(250)
pic.setMaximumHeight(250)
```

Comment: It works but not exactly as one might expect. When I set the max. width in fact I get smaller widget but it also just "crops" the image and only shows a portion of the original image (like 1/4 of it). So I resized the original image with another tool to the exactly number of pixels I specified with your solution and now it works! By the way you have a typo (pic.setMaximunHeight -> pic.setMaximumHeight). Thanks for your answer.